# Black screen while installing Debian 8.8

Tags: debian, ubuntu, grub, debian-installer

I wanted to install Debian 8.8 on my laptop which was using ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I downloaded the netinst and used rufus to burn it on a USB. I booted on the USB and I got the menu screen, but when I select install or graphics install I get a black screen (but the backlight is on and my external monitor on hdmi is not connecting). If I disable Uefi, I can get passed the problem; but grub fails to install.

I tried to install Ubuntu again but the laptop's display (blacklight is on) does not work but my external monitor does.

BTW I'm trying to install the OS on my nvme ssd which worked on the Ubuntu not Debian.

My question is, what is wrong and how do I fix this?

My laptop has:

- Intel i7 7700HQ
- 2x 8gb corsair ram
- nvidia gtx 1070
- 250gb Samsung 960 evo nvme ssd
- 1tb seagate hdd

Edit:
I just went on try Ubuntu before install and ran `xrandr - - listmonitors` and I only got the output of the external hdmi monitor.

Comment: A laptop with a NVidia GTX 1070? This is probably an Optimus set-up, i.e. the laptop can use either Intel iGPU for power savings, or the discrete NVidia GPU for display performance. The fact that Ubuntu's `xrandr --listmonitors` shows only the external monitor probably means you have a "muxless Optimus" setup: some displays/connectors are wired only to one GPU and the rest only to the other one. The Intel iGPU probably needs some firmware files that may not install by default on Debian unless you include the non-free part of the Debian repository. The NVidia GPU may require a backport kernel.

Answer (score 0):

To install debian on your SSD you should:

- have a [kernel version at least 3.2](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization#Basics).
- Install the `grub-efi` , the legacy grub isn't compatible.

You can repair the current debian installation , Enable the UEFi from your bios setting , Boot from debian live USB or Ubuntu .... , then create your chroot .

Add backports to your `sources.list`. update and install a new kernel from backports. once done install the `grub-efi` from backports.

Solving the black screen: Installing the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package from backports will solve the problem.

There is an example how to solve the black screen on [debian-wiki : Installing Debian On ThinkpadX1 Carbon 4thGen PCIe_SSD jessie](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Thinkpad/X1%20Carbon%204thGen%20PCIe_SSD/jessie)

The easy way is to install debian [testing](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/) with the `4.9` kernel version.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the ssd problem but what about the black screen problem? I can't see anything!

Comment: I don't think that can help since it's about black screen after installing debian